# How to query aws resources using boto3 and asyncio? Is this possible?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, boto3, python-asyncio

I have an existing code that queries AWS for resources one after another, filtering based on the resource name. The current implementation is linear and moves from one function for each resource to the next, creating the respective clients and querying aws using the clients. This of course consumes a lot of time. Is it possible to run each of these functions in an asynchronous fashion? Code flow looks like the snippet below with lot more resource queries.
Any inputs/suggestions would be helpful.

```
def query_acm():
    client = boto3.client('acm', region_name=region)
    client.get_paginator('list_certificates')
    # filter and write to file
def query_asg():
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=region)
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
    # paginate filter and write to file
def main():
    query_acm()
    query_asg()
```

Comment: Did you see the discussion here? https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/458

Comment: Thanks @MarkB for sharing the link, but this issue has been open for around 3 years and people still seem to have issues with the available solutions. I did explore aiobotocore option a bit, but my need here is relatively simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to run them in parallel, but for that I would suggest you to use python's built-in easy to use concurrent.futures library.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import boto3

def query_acm():
    client = boto3.client('acm', region_name=region)
    client.get_paginator('list_certificates')
    # filter and write to file
def query_asg():
    client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=region)
    paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_auto_scaling_groups')
    # paginate filter and write to file

def main():

    with concurrent.futures.Executor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(query_acm), executor.submit(query_asg)]

    for f in as_completed(futures):
        # Do what you want with f.result(), for example:
        print(f.result())
```

You can pass parameters and get response for each function call as well. [Read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or follow [some examples](http://masnun.com/2016/03/29/python-a-quick-introduction-to-the-concurrent-futures-module.html) on concurrent.futures.

Comment: Thanks, this worked with one catch. I had a decorator @write_to_file over a method that calls 
with concurrent.futures.Executor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(query_acm), executor.submit(query_asg)]
The code now works only without the decorator. With the decorator it is forever on the wait. I suppose there is a deadlock. Any insights there? Thank you for sharing your detailed post too.
How do i make my decorator work with concurrency?

Comment: @Jey, you are welcome.
There's an issue while using multiprocessing with functions having decorator. You can use a wrapper function without decorators that eventually calls your decorator functions.

Comment: yeah, I tried the same and it worked. Thanks and cheers mate!